# Tag Merge Discussion: process, development-process

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

[process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process) -> [development-process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-process)

I'm not sure how to work this one. I think we need to differentiate between business processes (there's already a [business-process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-process) tag with 8 questions) and process models/methodologies. I don't like the name "development-process", though, since a typical process model covers everything from requirements through end-of-life of a project. I suppose it depends on how you define "development" - it could be the development of a project or it could mean the actual construction/building/development phase of a project. I want to know what the community thinks on this guy, though.

Some manual work to ensure that questions about things that aren't process methodologies (such as [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91621/guidelines-for-html-css-js-optimization-process)) aren't rolled into the tag about process models and methodologies, whatever tag that may be. I also do think that process models and methodologies should be grouped into a single tag. An option for this would be to settle on a name for process questions and then make process-model and process-methodology synonyms with that tag.

Answer (score 2):

Process is a bit ambiguous. This could apply to several different meanings as in concurrency or multitasking. At least a few questions are tagged this way. So we have no 100% clear meaning and usage here.

Comment: Yeah. A manual pass of everything tagged process would be needed. If it's a question about concurrency or multitasking, it should probably have those tags, not an ambiguous tag like process. I don't know what tags exist for concurrency and parallelism related topics, though - I would have to look and see.

Comment: No, I think [tag:process] should be used exclusively for the technical meaning of a process running on a computer. Everything regarding development in general should be retagged [tag:development-process]. Though this would most likely be the case for many old questions.

Comment: After I'm done with [tag:software-engineering], I might go through [tag:process] and make sure that everything is tagged appropriately. Unless someone comes up with a better idea, "process" will be processes that run on a computer, not development processes or methods of doing something.