# Process tag clean-up complete. Please deal with?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

Per a [previous discussion here on Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/tag-merge-discussion-process-development-process), I went through all questions tagged [process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process). There were no questions about concurrency or IPC with this tag, so it was irrelevant, but I would recommend something along the lines of [concurrency](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concurrency) or [inter-process-communication](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inter-process-communication) for these questions. I used the tag [development-process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-process) to account for process model and methodology questions and simply removed the tag from "how do I do X" questions that didn't involve a formal process or concurrency issues.

I'm not sure how, but this tag is now dead to me.

Comment: thanks for doing that -- I kicked the tag process so it should remove any orphans immediately.

Comment: @Jeff Is it also blacklisted or anything like that? If not, I suppose the question is "should it be?"

Comment: you can propose a synonym if it recurs

Comment: @Jeff The only problem is what is it a synonym for? In software development, process could refer to an instance of a running program, converting data between forms, a development methodology, business processes (especially in the context of business process modeling). I'm not sure it's possible to synonym-ize "process" by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no questions tagged with [process](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process), so it'll go away in the next day. If someone recreates it, we can deal with more permanent solutions.

Comment: Yeah. I got rid of the tag from every question that formerly had the tag and replaced it with a better tag (or, in most cases, tags).